# Array to tuple conversion python

Tags: python, arrays, tuples, data-conversion

I have an array that looks like this

```
   [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and I would like a list of tuples that looks like this:

```
[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)]
```

What is the most convenient way to do this in python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
zip( a[:-1], a[1:] )
```

see `help(zip)` or the website [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) of `zip`.

Since `zip` limits itself to the shorter sequence,

```
zip(a, a[1:])
```

works too.

EDIT:

Steven brought up the interesting point that if `a` is very long, doing the implicit copy to get the separate pyObject that is `a[1:]` is problematic. In this case, you might want to use `numpy` and its options to get a view on the same data with but a offset.

Comment: It should be `zip( a[:-1], a[1:] )`

Comment: May as well reduce it to `zip(a, a[1:])` since it only zips up to the end of the shortest argument.

Comment: Your answer is practical and pythonic.  However if the OP needs to generate the tuples on the fly, he can use the [recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) for `pairwise` from the `iterools` module docs.  This would be useful if the data were coming from a very large in-memory list or a large external file.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Where does hat "needs them on the fly" come from? Op said he "has arrays and need a list of tuples". I appreciate your memory argument, though.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using list comprehension and list slicing, you iterate over the elements upto `len(a) - 1` and on each iteration slice the elements form `current_index` and the element next to it.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [tuple(a[i:i+2]) for i in range(len(a)-1)]
print b

>>> [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

Comment: this returns a list of lists, not a list of tuples.

Comment: you've fixed that :)